# Strange issue with Android 6.0 and view backround colors

Tags: java, android

This happens only on Android 6.0 (Marshmallow). I have set my style.xml files to use the three colors:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/oteal_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/teal</item>
</style>
```

And in my Toolbar, a Tab View, and a single view... I reference the color using

```
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
```

However strangely when I open an activity with a view using that color... it's white (or most likely, set to transparent). When I return to the activity, the toolbar and tabview as well become transparent. Interestingly even if I hardcode the color into the view, it still happens. If I make the hardcoded value different (just by 1), the color shows up again.

It has something to do with the style, but I am not sure what. Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Which colors your using?

Comment: colorPrimary is set to #009876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. For a toolbar animation thing I was doing, I set the background to alpha 0.

mActivity.getToolbar().getBackground().setAlpha(0);

This background was being shared by other views. It seems in Android 6, the OS now shares the same object with various view so setting it to 0 here, will effect any other view in the app. My fix is to reset the alpha on fragment destruction.